# Is Canoval Dagger the only item that uses Silver and Star Crystals?

Tags: danmachi-memoria-freese

Is Canoval Dagger the only item that uses Silver and Star Crystals? I want to know if I should save them for something else or go ahead and craft the Canoval Dagger.

Answer (score -1):

For now the only thing they can be used for is the daggers and an addition to that statement I said you should probably start collecting them for future use.